# web Service error: <customErrors mode="Off"/>

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0

I have  web service with a web method "Login". I test it in my client and on the server. On my client and my server "Login" doesn't have any error and run trusly.

My server has two network card and  I don't have access to second IP  in my local network. I test "Login" in my client by first IP and in server by second IP and it was true.

A client in another network that it accesses to second IP have error when use "Login".

They have the below error:

```
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is
configured to show verbose error messages using <customErrors
mode="Off"/>. Consider using <customErrors mode="On"/> or
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/> in production environments.-->
--.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
asyncCall)    at
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
NationalBillingService.Login(UserInfo User)    --- End of inner
exception stack trace ---    at
System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)    at
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  
at Storm.UI.Forms.FormMainOps.clo@651.Invoke(Object[] methodParams@41)
at
<StartupCode$Storm>.$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_2.Invoke(DoWorkEventArgs
dArgs)    at
<StartupCode$Storm>.$Type.bgworker.run@51@57_1.Invoke(Object sender,
DoWorkEventArgs e)    at
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
argument)
```

I do this setting to my web.config . it doesn't solve the problem.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

What should I do to solve that client error?

Comment: *What should I do to solve that client error?* Can you elaborate? Do you mean you don't want to show them the error?

Comment: I want that they can do "Login" without error!

Comment: Without looking at the relevant code we won't be able to help you